# How do I keep input code on the same line as the print code

Tags: python, io

Completely new to coding and this site, so I know this is going to seem like a silly or extremely obvious question. I've tried looking on the site for answers, but I don't know if the answers already given would work on this, or I simply don't know how to input the answers given into my code.

I want the "years old" print to appear right after you input the age, but on the same line.

```
name = input ("Hello, my name is ")
age = input("I am ")
print ("years old")
job = input("I am a ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something like this:

```
name = input("Enter your name : ")
age = input("Enter your age : ")

print(f"My name is {name} and I am {age} years old")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
name = input ("Name: ")
age = input("Age: ")
print ("Hello, My name is {}, I am {} years old".format(name, age))
```